# To set radio button in the modal from a value using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

I am trying to set the radio button in the Modal by using the data attribute value. It works fine if I remove the hidden modal code. However, i want that code as I also use it to add new students(which I have not provided in code) and so i clear it on closing. The textbox works fine but the radio button stops working after selecting one student and then selecting another student.

For ex, I edit John and it works as expected. Now after clicking John and then i close and click Jane the radio button does not work. Is there a way where I can clear the content of the controls on closing the modal but also get the values back in on selection?

```js
$(document).on('click', '.editStudent', function(e) {
  var row = $(this).closest('tr');
  var name = row.find('td.name').text().trim();
  var qualified = $(this).attr("data-qualified");
  if (name != null && name != "" && name != undefined) {
    $("#ModalName").val(name);
  }
  if (qualified != null && qualified != "" && qualified != undefined) {
    $("input[name='ModalQualified']").val([qualified.toLowerCase()])
  }
  $('#EditModal').modal('toggle');
})

$('#EditModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e) {
  $(this)
    .find("input,textarea,select")
    .val('')
    .end()
    .find("input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio]")
    .prop("checked", false)
    .end();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<table id="tblStudent">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="display:none;">Id</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" value="id1" /></td>
      <td class="name">John</td>
      <td><a title="Edit" class="btn btn-xs editStudent" data-qualified="false"> Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" value="id2" /></td>
      <td class="name">Jane</td>
      <td><a title="Edit" class="btn btn-xs editStudent" data-qualified="true"> Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" value="id3" /></td>
      <td class="name">Jim</td>
      <td><a title="Edit" class="btn btn-xs editStudent" data-qualified="false"> Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>



<div id="EditModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;  </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit Student</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Student</label><br />
              <input type="text" id="ModalName" class="form-control medium" />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="Refrigeration">Qualified</label>
              <input type="radio" id="ModalQualified" name="ModalQualified" value="true" />Yes
              <input type="radio" id="ModalQualified" name="ModalQualified" value="false" style="margin-left: 15px;" />No<br />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `$('#EditModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e) {` should that not be `$('#EditModal').on('click','hidden.bs.modal', function(e) {`

Comment: @mplungjan Doesn't change anything. The issue persists.

Answer (score 1):

The ID of the radio would have to be different, and then use prop of element:

```
if(qualified.toLowerCase() == 'true')

$('#ModalQualifiedY').prop('checked',true)

else

$('#ModalQualifiedN').prop('checked',true)
```

Comment: I do not want to change the ID of the radio button. Need it to remain the same as that is how they are bound to the serer side in ASP.Net Core

Comment: The 'checked' property should receive a boolean value, not a string.

Comment: It is not a good practice to use two identical IDs, in an HTML page